# Count number of basic instruction and their type

Tags: python-3.x

I have some code (few hundreds of lines) and i would like to reproduce the code on some "real" controller.
I would like to predict how long the code would take to run by counting how many instructions (basic arithmetic, type of operation (floating point, binary, etc..)

And i wonder if it is possible to do on python (if yes how so ? haven't found anything yet)

---

I know there is a time feature to measure how long it takes to run the code but the calculation power of my PC and the controller i plan to use are not the same.

Also i tried counting it myself but it is quite a pain and subject to errors

---

Ideal result would be like:

- X number of basic arithmetic operation using INT
- Y number of basic arithmetic operation using FLOAT
- Z binary operation

etc ...

Thank you

Comment: By default, I do not think this kind of information is available. However, you could implement it by making a custom class and overriding the arithmetic operations. Here's a link to some info on operator overloading https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operator-overloading-in-python/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question got me thinking. I wrote a little framework for how you might implement something like this. Basically you create your own number class and a collection to hold them all. Then you over-ride the default operators and increment a variable every time you enter those functions. Note that this is NOT robust.. There's no error checking and it assumes that all operations are done with the custom class objects.

```py
from collections import defaultdict # Acts like a dictionary,  but every time you add a key, the value defaults to a specified value

class Collection(object): # Use this to hold your custom types
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
        return

    def add_item(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)


class myFloat(object): # Your custom float class
    def __init__(self, val, collection):
        """ val is the value, collection is the Collections object where we will place your object """
        self.val = float(val)
        self.op_counts = defaultdict(int) # a dictionary where values default to an integer, 0.
        collection.add_item(self) # Add this object to the collection

    def __add__(self, other): # Called when you use + on two myFloat
        self.op_counts["+"] += 1 # Adds 1 to the number of "+" used
        return self.val + other.val # returns the result. 

    def __sub__(self, other): # Called when you use - on two myFloat
        self.op_counts["-"] += 1
        return self.val - other.val

    def __mul__(self, other): # Called when you use * on two myFloat
        self.op_counts["*"] += 1
        return self.val * other.val

    def __truediv__(self, other): # Called when you use / on two myFloat
        self.op_counts["/"] += 1
        return self.val / other.val

### EXAMPLE     
import random
ops = ["+", "-", "*", "/"] 
# We should create a separate Collection object for each custom type we have.
# Since we only have myFloat, we make one Collection object to hold the myFloats.

float_collection = Collection()

# This instantiates a myFloat object with val=7.12 and uses your float_collection
y = myFloat(7.12, float_collection) 

for x in range(1, 1000):
    op = random.choice(ops) # Pick a random operation
    xx = myFloat(x, float_collection) # Instantiate another myFloat
    # Now perform the operation on xx and y. eval evaluates the string but
    # opens the door for security holes if you are worried about hackers. CAREFUL.
    eval(f"y{op}xx") # Remove this line and use the one below if your python < 3.6
    # eval("y{}xx".format(op)) 

print("### RESULTS ###")
result_op_counts = defaultdict(int) # We use this to count up our results

# Sorry for the confusing syntax. The items parameter of the Collection object
# is NOT the same as the items() method for dictionaries.

# float_collection.items is a list of your myFloats.
# the items() method for dictionary returns a dict_items object that you can iterate through.
# This loop tallies up all the results
for myFloatObj in float_collection.items: 
    for op, ct in myFloatObj.op_counts.items():
        result_op_counts[op] += ct

# And this loop prints them.
for k,v in result_op_counts.items():
    print(f"{k}: {v} operations") # Remove this line and use the one below if your python < 3.6
    # print("{}: {} operations".format(k, v))
```

This outputs

```
### RESULTS ###
*: 227 operations
/: 247 operations
+: 275 operations
-: 250 operations
```

Comment: Thank you very much it looks great.
I'll see how i can implement that as i have quite a lot of variables !
Also i'm pretty new to python and you use a lot of pythonic functions i've never used but ill work on that

Comment: Added comments. Here are some useful links: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary-items-method/, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operator-overloading-in-python/,

Comment: Thank you for your time. I appreciate a lot

Comment: I would like to do this:
j = 0

and in a for loop do
j += 1

How can i do that with your code ? I can't figure out the eval() part i think


** EDIT: I think i got it : j.val=eval(f"j+one") **

Comment: I don't think you need to use `eval` in your code. I only needed it in my example to help me use the random operator since you can't assign operators to variables. For your purposes: `j.val = j+one` would work. (I'm guessing you did something like `one=myInt(1, int_collection)` earlier)

Comment: Got it thanks. I think with your code i had an idea for my problem but it is "fast and dirty". I'm creating one "global" variable to count each type of operation and i increment it where i do such operation. 
This add quite a lot of lines but it works fine